# Performance difference between .NET method (in .dll) and reflected version

Tags: c#, .net, dll, assemblies

I have been attempting to optimize a JavaScript encode function (in C#) to improve its performance (in an overall attempt of improving the performance of an enterprise web application). We attempted to use the .NET `HttpUtility.JavaScriptStringEncode` but it does not encode the way our data layer is anticipating (and changing the data layer is not on the table).

Using the RedGate profiler tool I determined the best performance of our function is around 8% of the total page load. When I use the .NET function (on a page that accepts it), it comes in at around .08% of total page load. We reflected the .NET function to see what sorcery they were working and when I copied the reflected code into the function and ran it directly, it performed at around 10%.

I'm curious as to why. How is the .NET function prepared differently to award such a performance increase?

I apologize in advance but I cannot paste up the function that we are using, but I don't think that should impact answering the question.

Comment: Interesting. Just making sure, but you ran these benchmarks under Release mode on the same PC and page, right? Oh, and did you run the test multiple times in the same run to make sure the JIT had generated all the code before you benchmarked it?

Comment: Did the actual runtime change, or just the fraction of overall page load?  Perhaps the page is more complex and the total is slower.

Comment: I'd try using the ServiceStack serializer (available via NuGet); it's fast but still reasonably flexible. As for performance measurements, try isolating the code into a unit test or similar, so you can make repeated iterations and easily compare various approaches. Benchmarking code that runs via IIS is usually not ideal as so many other factors can skew the results. Note that dll's shipping with .NET usually are precompiled and so need not be JIT'ed at runtime.

Comment: The .NET function is prepared differently in the sense that it was made by wizards at Microsoft.

Comment: @Cameron - Yes to all of them. interestingly enough, release vs. debug mode had no effect on performance

Comment: @Ben - Yes, I looked at the actual runtime (in ms) as well as the encode method is currently the workhorse of the page. It changed as well (my version was around 25ms, the .NET (precompilied) was 0.4ms).

Comment: @Merrdin Are you sure you're not including the JIT cost into that? In other words, does the same happen if you execute the same function for the second time?

Comment: @Merrdin: Hmm. Have you tried running NGEN and putting the assembly in the GAC?

Comment: @svick - Yes, I ran it several times before looking at the performance. I then took an average of a few runs to rule out any outliers.

Comment: @Cameron - No, I haven't tried that. I will take a stab at those ideas on Monday. Thanks!

Comment: What did you find when you ran NGen?

Comment: @Merrdin: Have you got any final conclusions?

Comment: So, after running NGen, there was no change in the performance of either my code or the reflected .NET code. The assembled .NET is still heads and tails above anything I can write. So, the only conclusion is I have no idea how they did it or what might be going on.

Comment: You could post your code and the reflected code so we could take a look

Answer (score 1):

Can you compare the IL code produced after you paste the reflected code into your library with the IL code present in the .NET library? The compiler switch being used to compile can cause such differences.